# Proving the Marginal Distribution of a $\text{Gamma}(2,\lambda)$ Joint Distribution follows an Exponential

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, marginal-distribution

I derived the bivariate joint distribution with a transformation from two exponential distributions with $\lambda = 1.5$ for $X,Y$ and $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$. With $X=(U+V)/2$ and $Y=(U-V)/2$ I derived the joint $f_{u,v}$ as follows:

Skipping a few steps:

$f_{u,v}=\frac{4}{9}e^{\frac{2}{3}(\frac{-(U+V)}{2}-\frac{U-V}{2})}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=$

$f_{u,v}=\frac{2}{9}e^{-\frac{2}{3}U}$ for $0<V<U$

So to find the marginal, I take the integral with respect to V. I should expect a $\text{Gamma}(2,1.5)$ distribution.

$f_u=\int_{0}^{U}\frac{2}{9}e^{-\frac{2}{3}U} dv$

$f_u=\frac{2}{9}Ue^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

The above should be $\frac{4}{9}$ not $\frac{2}{9}$. I have a feeling the bounds should be $0<V<2U$. I'm probably missing something really basic, I just am not able to show why that would be the bounds.

Comment: You seem to have a sticky 'caps' key and these symbols are case sensitive.  Please clean your keyboard so you don't confuse $u$ with $U$ .

Comment: Also, $V$ may be negative as it is $X-Y$ and $Y$ may be greater than $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are exponentially distributed, the domain for each of $X$ and $Y$ is $[0,\infty)$.

Defining $U=X+Y$ means the support for $U$ is $[0;\infty)$.

Also *when given* $U$ the conditional support for $Y$ is $[0;U]$ (as it may *not* have a value greater than $U$), and $X=U-Y$ (of course).

Now $V=X-Y$, or $V=U-2Y$, so when given $U$, the *conditional* support for $V$ is $[U-2U;U-0]$, that is: $[-U;U]$

---

So the joint support for $\langle U,V\rangle$ is $\{\langle u,v\rangle:0\leq u, -u\leq v\leq u\}\\=\{\langle u,v\rangle: \lvert v\rvert\leq u\}$